# Create columns with a loop

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project and in the Database I want to create a table with one column and more columns in a loop to the count of a List defined somewhere in my solution. How to achieve this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [tag] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL

    while... <something becomes MyList.Count>
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Comment: You would build an SQL string looping over the list appending the column definitions, then execute it.  Often programmatically creating a variable number of columns is a sign that whatever that data is belongs on rows in  its own table.

Comment: Ok, but where to add this sql string and it's execution? No it is not a variable of columns. It's more like I the list of items I have is of variable size and I will update it regulary, but I would also want to add a column for the respective element I wanted it to be more automaitc.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is a sign of really bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have write a separate query for that looping after creation, which would be an `ALTER TABLE`.

Like,

```
WHILE(condition)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD column_name datatype
END
```

Here, the condition should be the count. The column name depends on how you pass the values. I would pass them as XML data in table format, then convert it to a table in SQL and then loop through them while altering.

Like,

```
WHILE((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM temp))
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN '+(SELECT TOP 1 column_name FROM temp)+' NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    DELETE FROM temp WHERE temp.id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM temp)
END
```

Hope this works :)